# How to get mysql result with rounded decimal place to 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query..

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.description,sum(sl.qty*sl.factor) as qty
FROM sale_line as sl
LEFT JOIN sale as s ON(sl.sale_id=s.sale_id)
LEFT JOIN product as p ON(p.product_id=sl.product_id)
ORDER BY sl.product_id DESC;
```

I want to get "sum(sl.qty*sl.factor) as qty" field to round into two decimal places.
Eg. if the result get '13.170000484884', I want to round into '13.17' to the result.

Comment: copy query here.don't make image for it. you can use `ROUND()` function of mysql. here it is link: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROUND()` funtion:

```
ROUND(sum(sl.qty*sl.factor),2) as qty
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.description,ROUND(sum(sl.qty*sl.factor),2) as qty
FROM sale_line as sl
LEFT JOIN sale as s ON(sl.sale_id=s.sale_id)
LEFT JOIN product as p ON(p.product_id=sl.product_id)
ORDER BY sl.product_id DESC;
```